# Powershell to Break up CSV by Number of Row

Tags: powershell

So I am now tasked with getting constant reports that are more than 1 Million lines long.

My last question did not explain all things so I'm tryin got do a better question.

I'm getting a dozen + daily reports that are coming in as CSV files. I don't know what the headers are or anything like that as I get them.

They are huge. I cant open in excel.

I wanted to basically break them up into the same report, just each report maybe 100,000 lines long.

The code I wrote below does not work as I keep getting a

```
Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
```

I am guessing I need a better way to do this.

I just need this file broken down to a more manageable size.
It does not matter how long it takes as I can run it over night.

I found this on the internet, and I tried to manipulate it, but I cant get it to work.

```
$PSScriptRoot

write-host $PSScriptRoot

$loc = $PSScriptRoot

$location = $loc

# how many rows per CSV?
$rowsMax = 10000; 

# Get all CSV under current folder
$allCSVs = Get-ChildItem "$location\Split.csv"


# Read and split all of them
$allCSVs | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host $_.Name;
    $content = Import-Csv "$location\Split.csv"
    $insertLocation = ($_.Name.Length - 4);
    for($i=1; $i -le $content.length ;$i+=$rowsMax){
    $newName = $_.Name.Insert($insertLocation, "splitted_"+$i)
    $content|select -first $i|select -last $rowsMax | convertto-csv -NoTypeInformation | % { $_ -replace '"', ""} | out-file $location\$newName -fo -en ascii
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried lowering the `$rowsMax` Variable to something like 1000 and see if that works?

Comment: Ya it has thrown the memory error even at 50 lines for some reason.

Comment: How many csv files are in that location you pulling from?

Answer (score 3):

**The key is not to read large files into memory *in full***, which is what you're doing by capturing the output from `Import-Csv` in a *variable* (`$content = Import-Csv "$location\Split.csv"`).

That said, while **using a *single pipeline* would solve your memory problem, performance will likely be poor**, because you're converting from and back to CSV, which incurs a lot of overhead.

Even reading and writing the files *as text* with `Get-Content` and `Set-Content` is slow, however.
Therefore, I suggest **a .NET-based approach for processing the files as text**, which should substantially speed up processing.

The following code demonstrates this technique:

```
Get-ChildItem $PSScriptRoot/*.csv | ForEach-Object {

    $csvFile = $_.FullName

    # Construct a file-path template for the sequentially numbered chunk
    # files; e.g., "...\file_split_001.csv"
    $csvFileChunkTemplate = $csvFile -replace '(.+)\.(.+)', '$1_split_{0:000}.$2'

    # Set how many lines make up a chunk.
    $chunkLineCount = 10000

    # Read the file lazily and save every chunk of $chunkLineCount
    # lines to a new file.
    $i = 0; $chunkNdx = 0
    foreach ($line in [IO.File]::ReadLines($csvFile)) {
        if ($i -eq 0) { ++$i; $header = $line; continue } # Save header line.
        if ($i++ % $chunkLineCount -eq 1) { # Create new chunk file.
            # Close previous file, if any.
            if (++$chunkNdx -gt 1) { $fileWriter.Dispose() }

            # Construct the file path for the next chunk, by
            # instantiating the template with the next sequence number.
            $csvFileChunk = $csvFileChunkTemplate -f $chunkNdx
            Write-Verbose "Creating chunk: $csvFileChunk"

            # Create the next chunk file and write the header.
            $fileWriter = [IO.File]::CreateText($csvFileChunk)
            $fileWriter.WriteLine($header)
        }
        # Write a data row to the current chunk file.
        $fileWriter.WriteLine($line)
    }
    $fileWriter.Dispose() # Close the last file.

}
```

Note that the above code creates BOM-less UTF-8 files; if your input contains ASCII-range characters only, these files will effectively be ASCII files.

---

Here's the **equivalent single-pipeline solution**, which is likely to be substantially slower.

```
Get-ChildItem $PSScriptRoot/*.csv | ForEach-Object {

    $csvFile = $_.FullName

    # Construct a file-path template for the sequentially numbered chunk
    # files; e.g., ".../file_split_001.csv"
    $csvFileChunkTemplate = $csvFile -replace '(.+)\.(.+)', '$1_split_{0:000}.$2'

    # Set how many lines make up a chunk.
    $chunkLineCount = 10000

    $i = 0; $chunkNdx = 0
    Get-Content -LiteralPath $csvFile | ForEach-Object {
        if ($i -eq 0) { ++$i; $header = $_; return } # Save header line.
        if ($i++ % $chunkLineCount -eq 1) { # 
            # Construct the file path for the next chunk.
            $csvFileChunk = $csvFileChunkTemplate -f ++$chunkNdx
            Write-Verbose "Creating chunk: $csvFileChunk"
            # Create the next chunk file and write the header.
            Set-Content -Encoding ASCII -LiteralPath $csvFileChunk -Value $header
        }
        # Write data row to the current chunk file.
        Add-Content -Encoding ASCII -LiteralPath $csvFileChunk -Value $_
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option from linux world - split command. To get it on windows just install git bash, then you'll be able to use many linux tools in your CMD/powershell.
Below is the syntax to achieve your goal:

```
split  -l 100000 --numeric-suffixes --suffix-length 3 --additional-suffix=.csv sourceFile.csv outputfile
```

It's very fast. If you want you can wrap split.exe as a cmdlet

Comment: `split` is definitely the fastest option (if installed), but note that it is not enough by itself, as the additional chunks will not be full CSV files in the absence of a _header row_. (I'm assuming that the input files come with a header row and that the chunks should each have it, but maybe that's not what the OP requires, given that their own attempt seems to omit the headers from the additional chunks too).